# is there a way to redirect stream to stdin in lua

Tags: file, input, lua, stdin

So I was trying to read a file with following method

```
file=io.open('test.txt', 'r')
io.input(file)
a=io.read()
print(a)
io.close(file)
```

Problem being, I don't really know how to redirect io.read back to stdin stream. I tried:

```
io.input(stdin)
a=io.read()
print(a)
```

Is there any way to make this work?

EDIT:
Problem solved by implying io.stdin instead of stdin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `io.input(io.stdin)` to set default stdin back.

Comment: I tried this, it raised 'lua: test.lua:7: standard input file is closed'

Comment: @RazorVE Because you closed the file manually

Comment: i have no idea how its supposed to be done. Can you make an example? @Spar

Comment: @RazorVE Sorry, misunderstand docs, read the source code. I edited the answer.

Comment: guess thats how its settled

Answer (score 2):

Instead of directing stream to stdin, Lua actually allows file:read(), which enable us to directly read from file.

Comment: I thought you did io.read(file) on purpose. It accepts filename btw.